# Configure git to only ask for password once with timeout

Tags: linux, ssh, git, passwords, bitbucket.org

If I execute `git pull` or `git push`, then I always get asked for a password.

I generated a public/private key pair on rackspeed.

I opened my project in Bitbucket: **Settings -> General -> Access keys**
and added my public key.

Then I configured git like [seen here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-fix-git-always-asking-for-user-credentials/), so that it remembers the password for 600 seconds.

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=600'
```

I made sure that my git url is not https:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:company/example.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:company/example.git (push)
```

Then I executed `git pull`. It asked for the password for the first time. Then I executed `git pull` again, but it still asks for the password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using an SSH remote, you're being prompted for your password by OpenSSH, not Git.  Git doesn't handle passwords for OpenSSH (because it's non-trivial to do), so configuring Git's credential helpers will have no effect.

If you want to use Git's credential helpers, then you need to use an HTTPS remote.

Alternatively, you can use the `ssh-agent` program to save the password. You can run `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` in your shell and then run `ssh-add` to add the key.  You'll be prompted for your passphrase once, but not again in that terminal.

It's possible that your environment has already set up an SSH agent for you.  You can run `env | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and if it outputs anything, you can just run `ssh-add` and don't need to run the first command.

Answer (score 2):

Make Git store the username and password and it will never ask for them.

```
 git config --global credential.helper store
```

Save the username and password for a session (cache it):

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

You can also set a timeout for the above setting:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=600'
```

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting). Use normal text instead of headlines.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Note timeout is in seconds

Answer (score -1):

Try using this on terminal to save your credentials:

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>
```

Git will not ask for password again on `git push` or `git pull`.

Also read: `git help credentials`

Comment: I don't want so save the credentials. I just want to store them temporarily until a timeout is reached as stated in my question...